# Increase scroll speed within combobox dropdown in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I wanted to stop the infinite scroll that the UWP combobox does when in tablet mode.

using the following I have managed to achieve this

```
<ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
```

However, scrolling with touch is very slow and sluggish and doesnt keep the same fluidity that the standard carousel layout would do. When scrolling with a mouse, it performs perfectly fine.

Is there any way I can either

a) easily override the carousel to prevent the repeating behaviour

or

b) increase the fluidity and scrolling speed of the stackpanel in the itempaneltemplate

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there is no way to achieve what you want with existing [ComboBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox). Refer the **Note** in the [**Remarks** of ComboBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox#remarks):

> [ComboBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox) uses a [CarouselPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.carouselpanel) as its [ItemsPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ItemsControl_ItemsPanel). **Using a different panel as the [ItemsPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ItemsControl_ItemsPanel) is not supported and might result in undesired behavior.**

So using `StackPanel` as the `ItemsPanel` is not recommended (although this might be a simple workaround for this problem in most case). And for [CarouselPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.carouselpanel), it does not provide a way to stop the infinite scroll.

I'd highly recommend you do not change this default behavior as it may break the  unified user experience and make users confused. If you do want to stop the infinite scroll, then you will need to create your own ComboBox. Also, you are welcome to submit a request for this feature through [UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform).

Comment: And thats exactly what is happening. Thanks for clearing that up, seems i missed that remark. Im surprised the CaroselPanel doesnt include an option to disable infinite scroll

Comment: @Takarii As its name, `CarouselPanel` is used for "carousel", that would be why it doesn't have option to disable infinite scroll. You may submit a request through UserVoice for this function.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to regain the inertial scrolling when the ItemsPanel is set to a StackPanel by setting the VerticalSnapPointsType property of the ScrollViewer inside the ComboBox template to 'None' (default is 'OptionalSingle').

This results in the following style for the ComboBox:

```
<Style x:Name="ComboBoxWithoutCircularScroll" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundAltMediumBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundListMediumBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="FocusedPressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="FocusedDropDown">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DropDownStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <SplitOpenThemeAnimation ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter" OffsetFromCenter="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder" OpenedLength="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <SplitCloseThemeAnimation ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter" OffsetFromCenter="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder" OpenedLength="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" FontWeight="{ThemeResource ComboBoxHeaderThemeFontWeight}" FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}" Margin="{ThemeResource ComboBoxHeaderThemeMargin}" Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"/>
                    <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <Border x:Name="HighlightBackground" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextBaseHighBrush}" Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"/>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                    <FontIcon x:Name="DropDownGlyph" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE0E5;" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0,10,10,10" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                        <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeHighBrush}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownBorderThickness}" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,-1,0,-1">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" MinWidth="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownContentMinWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" VerticalSnapPointsType="None" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" VerticalSnapPointsAlignment="Near" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                                <ItemsPresenter Margin="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownContentMargin}"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you feel the ComboBox needs a property to disable the circular scrolling, please vote on [this suggestion at UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/20321650-add-property-to-combobox-to-disable-circular-scrol).